# Intel UHD 630 graphics fails after upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: boot, updates, intel-graphics, 19.10

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. The update went smoothly, but system boot into graphics mode fails with the new kernel 5.3.0-19. This applies not only to X but also Plymouth. Starting system in text mode is possible. Instead of gdm login, I got a blinking purple screen. When started in graphics mode, it hangs on Plymouth (black screen). Nomodeset works, but 1024x768 only is provided.

I'm able to boot the system correctly on old kernel 5.0.0-32 which works fine.

I have Intel UHD 630 graphics from the Intel Core i7-9700 APU.

Comment: Update: Booting Ubuntu 19.10 Live from USB stick gives as error:

`Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed`
`[drm:drm_calc_timestamp_constants [drm]] *ERROR* crtc 66: Cant't calculate constants, dotclock = 0~`

Comment: Are you up to date with the drivers from your manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same or a similar problem and in my case the solution is a simple one:
My boot gets stuck at the purple screen at every 19.10 system update. I found out that the Nvidia card at boot switches to a hypothetical second screen, sets it as primary and shows only the purple-blank secondary. When I move the mouse to the right, the mouse pointer appears coming from the left side of the screen - hence there is a second screen to the left of my laptop that I can't see. But I can access it, typing

Enter 
(My login password)
Enter

and Ubuntu starts normally. the first time it happened it also showed me a blank desktop since also in GUI the primary desktop was the not-connected second screen. Changing the screen options on the laptop via shortcut (Fn - F5 or F6 in my case) restored the single screen. I then changed the screen options to single screen again and I'm good until the next update.